# Update data on dropdown change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

On a change event from a dropdown list, I need to update part of the ViewModel and the events on the fullcalendar jquery plugin.  Updating the events on the plugin I have working.  But I don't understand the best way to update the ViewModel.Team view.  This is my first MVC application.  It is MVC4.
This is my markup.  I use multiple models for the controls.

```
<div id="manual_select_div" style="margin-top: 5px; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; height: 50%">             
    <div id="selectList">
        <label id="team_lbl">Team Members: </label>
        @foreach (var member in Model.Team)
        {
            <div id="@member.member_id.ToString()" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:@member.member_color" class="draggable"
                    data-event='{"title":"@member.member_name", "color":"@member.member_color"}'>@member.member_name</div>
        }
    </div>     
</div>
<div id='edit_calendar' style="float:right; width: 60%; height: 70%"></div>
```

When the data is initially displayed, I use an AJAX call for the calendar and multiple models for the team member data.

```
public ActionResult EditSchedule()
{
    string tstrUserID = string.Empty;
    EditScheduleViewModel editScheduleModel = new EditScheduleViewModel();
    try
    {
        //Get the UserID value
        tstrUserID = ParseUserID(this.User.Identity.Name);

        DataTable tdtTeamInfo = new DataTable();        
        List<string> tlstGroupIDs = new List<string>();

        //Database calls to get all of the data
        //Get the group information that user has the admin rights to edit schedule
        tdtGroupInfo = onCallDA.GetGroupByUserID(tstrUserID);
        //Get Team information using first groupID
        int tiGroupID = tdtGroupInfo.Select().First().Field<int>("ID");
        tdtTeamInfo = onCallDA.GetGroupMembersByGroupID(tiGroupID);
        //Populate the ViewModel
        List<Group> groups = tdtGroupInfo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Group
        {
            id = (string)(x["ID"].ToString()),
            name = (string)(x["Name"]),
            color = (string)(x["GroupColor"])
        }).ToList();

        editScheduleModel.Groups = groups;

        List<Member> team = tdtTeamInfo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Member
            {
                group_id = (string)(x["GroupID"].ToString()),
                member_id = (string)(x["MemberID"].ToString()),
                member_name = (string)(x["MemberName"]),
                member_color = (string)(x["MemberColor"])
            }).ToList();

        editScheduleModel.Team = team;

        return View(editScheduleModel);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }          
}
```

This is the onchange event. The calendar is correctly updated:

```
$("#group_name_select").change(function(){
    var groupSelected = $(this).val();
    var groupData = { iGroupID: groupSelected };

    $('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEventsForGroup", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(groupData),
            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];
                $(doc).each(function () {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start'),
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        id: $(this).attr('eventID'),
                        groupID: $(this).attr('objectID'),
                        color: $(this).attr('color'),
                        textColor: 'black'
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error fetching events!")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For completeness...this is how the calendar plugin is initialized in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

//Get the group from the dropdown to populate calendar    
var groupSelected = $('#group_name_select').val();
var groupData = { iGroupID: groupSelected };

$('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar({
    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: { month: 'MMMM' },
    defaultView: 'month',
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    droppable: true,
    editable: true,
    eventSources: [
       {
           events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '@Url.Action("GetEventsForGroup", "Home")',
                   data: JSON.stringify(groupData),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (doc) {
                       var events = [];
                       $(doc).each(function () {
                           events.push({
                               title: $(this).attr('title'),
                               start: $(this).attr('start'),
                               end: $(this).attr('end'),
                               id: $(this).attr('eventID'),
                               objectID: $(this).attr('objectID'),
                               color: $(this).attr('color'),
                               textColor: 'black',
                               editable: true
                           });

                       });
                       callback(events);
                   },
                   error: function () {
                       alert("There was an error fetching events!")
                   }
               });
           }
       }
    ],
    eventResizeStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        console.log('RESIZE START ' + event.title);

    },
    eventResizeStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        console.log('RESIZE STOP ' + event.title);
    },

    eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

        if (dayDelta >= 1 && !event.allDay) {
            revertFunc();

            for (var i = 0 ; i < dayDelta ; i++) {
                var newEvent = {
                    id: event.id,
                    objectID: event.objectID,
                    title: event.title,
                    color: event.color,
                    textColor: 'black',
                    start: new Date(event.start),
                    end: new Date(event.end),
                    allDay: event.allDay
                };

                newEvent.start.setDate(newEvent.start.getDate() + (i + 1));
                newEvent.end.setDate(newEvent.end.getDate() + (i + 1));
                $('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, 'stick');
            }
        }
    }
}); //end calendar initialization

//...other initialization stuff not relevant

}); //End document ready function
```

My question is how to I update the editScheduleModel.Team model?  Should it be an AJAX call like the calendar plugin? How do I update the model? Should I change how the team data is initialized and use AJAX calls?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**
I don't know if this is the best way..but I added the following code to the jquery change function to update the team member list:

```
 $("#group_name_select").change(function(){
    var groupSelected = $(this).val();
    var groupData = { iGroupID: groupSelected };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTeamMembers", "Home")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(groupData),
        success: function(team) {
            $(team).each(function () {
                alert('Team member: ' + $(this).attr('member_name'));
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("There was an error fetching events!")
        }          
    });
```

The correct names display in the alert.
The Controller method is this:

```
 public ActionResult UpdateTeamMembers(int iGroupID)
    {
        DatabaseAccess onCallDA = new DatabaseAccess();
        DataTable tdtTeamInfo = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            tdtTeamInfo = onCallDA.GetGroupMembersByGroupID(iGroupID);
            List<Member> team = tdtTeamInfo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Member
            {
                group_id = (string)(x["GroupID"].ToString()),
                member_id = (string)(x["MemberID"].ToString()),
                member_name = (string)(x["MemberName"]),
                member_color = (string)(x["MemberColor"])
            }).ToList();

            return Json(team, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }           
    }
```

I don't know how to set the values in the html. Initially, I set the values using the Team model:

```
<div id="selectList">
        <label id="team_lbl">Team Members: </label>
        @foreach (var member in Model.Team)
        {
            <div id="@member.member_id.ToString()" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:@member.member_color" class="draggable"
                    data-event='{"title":"@member.member_name", "color":"@member.member_color"}'>@member.member_name</div>
        }
    </div>
```

But how do I set the values above within the jquery change function?

**UPDATE**

I am able to update the 'divs' within the change event as shown below:

```
 $("#group_name_select").change(function(){
    var groupSelected = $(this).val();
    var groupData = { iGroupID: groupSelected };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTeamMembers", "Home")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(groupData),
        success: function(team) {
            $('div').remove('.draggable');
            $(team).each(function () {
                $('#selectList').prepend('<div id="' + $(this).attr('member_id') + '" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:' + $(this).attr('member_color') + '" class="draggable" data-event=\'{"title":"' + $(this).attr('member_name') + '", "color":"' + $(this).attr('member_color') + '"}\'>' + $(this).attr('member_name') + '</div>');
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("There was an error fetching events!")
        }
});
```

The divs are selectable and the color and text is correct but they are not draggable.  I checked that the class attribute is set correctly but I cannot drag the items on the calendar.
Does anyone have any idea why they are not draggable?  When initially displayed they are draggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need bind again this library, because jQuery bind only to exists elements. I replied here - [Update part of a model on change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088432/update-part-of-a-model-on-change-event/33090319#33090319)

And you need use this same code, but I think you not should use:

```
 $('div').remove('.draggable');
```

You should change this to select specific container, becuase now you remove draggable for all your div in page

```
 $('#selectList > div').remove('.draggable');
```